# Neovim colour scheme in Urxvt not rendering correctly

Tags: colors, vimrc, rxvt

I'm trying to use a 256 color theme in Neovim (this one: https://github.com/ayu-theme/ayu-vim), but can't get it to render correctly on Urxvt, even though it seems to support 256 colors:

[image: 256 colour support in Urxvt]

Here is the relevant portion of my `.vimrc`:

```
Plugin 'ayu-theme/ayu-vim'
...
syntax enable
set termguicolors
let ayucolor="light"
colorscheme ayu
```

The color scheme works in Neovim on XTerm and in `gvim`, making me suspect it's an issue with Urxvt. I've tested this with and without modifications to `Xresources`.

[image: Colour scheme in different environments]

I'm on Ubuntu with the `rxvt-unicode` and `rxvt-unicode-256color` packages installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be me misunderstanding what the `termguicolors` option entails in Vim. The `ayu` colour theme actually requires Truecolor support, which Urxvt does not have.

There is a good explanation of colour support in terminals:
https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728

This has finally given me a good enough reason to switch to Alacritty.